# How to configure Sonarqube scanner for java and javascript in the same project

Tags: javascript, java, sonarqube, code-coverage

I have been trying to set up sonar-scanner for a Maven project containing a java module (core) and a javascript module (web).

I am able to get either java coverage data scanned and presented on my local sonarqube server, or javascript, but not both.

Here is my sonar-project.properties file, where the sonar.modules property can have one of 4 values:

```
### below: select just one of the 4 possible values for sonar.modules
sonar.modules = core --> get java coverage data
sonar.modules = web --> get javascript coverage data
sonar.modules = core,web --> get only java coverage data
sonar.modules = web,core --> get only java coverage data

sonar.sources=src

# javascript coverage report
web.sonar.exclusions=src/main/webapp/js/lib/**/*.js
web.sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath = test-output/coverage/lcov.info

# java coverage report
core.sonar.java.binaries = target/classes
core.sonar.java.libraries = ../web/target/scheduler-web-3.5.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib
core.sonar.java.test.libraries = ../web/target/scheduler-web-3.5.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib
core.sonar.jacoco.reportPath = target/jacoco.exec
core.sonar.junit.reportsPath = target/surefire-reports
core.sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero = true
```

---

The key to my solution, based on the accepted answer below :

- No changes to the top-level POM.
- Added to web/pom.xml:

> ```
> <properties>
>     <sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>test-output/coverage/lcov.info</sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>
> </properties>
> ```

Essentially sonar did not know where to find my lcov file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the SonarQube Scanner with a dedicated `sonar-project.properties` file to run your analysis - but instead rely on the [Scanner for Maven](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-maven.html).

To see how to do this, simply take a look at how SonarQube itself (that contains both Java and JS) is analyzed:

- Go on its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/)
- And take a look at the [server/sonar-web/pom.xml](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/server/sonar-web/pom.xml) file of the Web module where you will notice:

```html
  <properties>
    <!-- self-analysis -->
    <sonar.sources>src/main/js,src/main/less</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests>src/main/js</sonar.tests>
    <sonar.test.inclusions>src/main/js/**/__tests__/**</sonar.test.inclusions>
    <sonar.exclusions>src/main/js/libs/third-party/**/*,src/main/js/libs/require.js,src/main/js/**/__tests__/**</sonar.exclusions>
    <yarn.script>build</yarn.script>
</properties>
```

Comment: The above answer put me on the right track. I added to the POM for each of the two modules I was interested in.

Comment: Curious why my question got down-voted. Willing to modify it.